Bug report - '.. every 40 minutes'
Just a bug? report. I just now joined Academia (I am a long-time user of many SE sites); I posted a question and ..

No issue to me, just lettin' y'all know, cheers.


resolved below


According to the official rate limiting guide, this is by design.

Users with < 125 rep on the current site [are rate limited on question-asking to] 40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network

